# I need some htaccess code to rewrite bad urls and deliver a 410

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can you help me with a mod rewrite for htaccess that would take a url and deliver a 410 redirect
It will depend on the first character after the domain name being "1"
because i want all urls with "1"after the domain name to be redirected

domain.com/1
followed by a wildcard
and that should delvier a 410

Any ideas?

I tried

```
RedirectMatch 410 ^/1(*).*$
```

but that does not work

thaks,George

Answer (score 0):

You are not  using a valid regex pattern. You should be using `^/1` .

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 410 ^/1
```

This will return a 410 error if you visit `example.com/1` or `example.com/1foobar` .

Comment: great! Thanks.
I have a site with 35 ursl noindexed that keep reappearing in a site; command even though delted several times
Then i found the /1 footprint and thought about htaccess whci i dont knw how to code

Comment: I need to deliver a 410 on this url
domain.com/shop

But the above line
RedirectMatch 410 ^/s 
redirects 
domain.com/shop/shampoo
which I don't want.

Is there some way i can do this with your code
RedirectMatch 410 ^/1


Thanks
George

Comment: i.e. just redirect
domain.com/shop  
not everything else after shop

Comment: @george If you want to redirect a specific uri ,you can use `RedirectMatch 410 ^/shop/?$`